# How i can query in mongoose to get the "answers" array where 'objective' inside the 'answers' array is "Awareness"

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, mongoose

I'm trying to get the list of 'answers' from "Response" mongoDB using mongoose in nodeJS where the 'objectives' array contain 'Awareness' and specific 'projectId' also. But it return all list.

```
Response.find({projectId: req.params.projectId,"answers.objectives": "Awareness"})
    .populate()
    .then(survey => {
        res.json(survey);
    }));
```

I tried mongoose find keyword but it dosen't work
This is mongoDB Structure:
[image: This is mongoDB Structure]

Comment: answers is an array not object check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positional operator `$` for nested array of objects for fetching only matched elements. See below :

```
Response.find({projectId: req.params.projectId,"answers.objectives": 
    "Awareness"},{"answers.objectives.$": 1})
.populate()
.then(survey => {
    res.json(survey);
}));
```